# Only Inserted the latest row on listview into sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am beginner android developer. I need your help. I want to insert my order into 2 tables of sqlite, tblorder and orderdtl. orderdtl inserted from multiple item of listview. when i try to save all. only the last row have been inserted into orderdtl there is no problem with other table. Can any body fix this problem? this is my code

```
btnsaveto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String orderid=orderid();
        String orderdate=orderdate();
        String notes = edtnotes.getText().toString();
        long outletid = Globals.outletid;
        order = dataSource.createorder(orderid, orderdate, notes, outletid);
        for(int i=0; i< Globals.mylist.size() ;i++){
            Globals.mylist.set(i, map1);
            map1.get(Id);
            map1.get(qty);
        orderdtl = dataSource.createorderdtl(orderid, Id, qty);
            Globals.mylist.remove(i);
        Toast.makeText(EntryTO.this, "masuk Order \n" +
                "ID :" + order.getorderid() +"\n" +
                "DATE:" + order.getorderdate() +"\n" +
                "NOTES :" + order.getnotes() +"\n" +
                "OUTLET ID" + order.getoutletid() +"\n" +
                "ID :" + orderdtl.getorderid() +"\n" +
                "ID PRODUK :" + orderdtl.getId() +"\n" +
                "QTY :" +orderdtl.getqty(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //Intent i3 = new Intent(EntryTO.this, ViewOrder.class);
        //startActivity(i3);
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume 'mylist' is an ArrayList of Hashmap. The first problem is this line:

```
Globals.mylist.set(i, map1);
```

That replaces the element at index 'i' with whatever map1 holds. Therefore map1 never changes within your loop and neither will the values 'Id' and 'qty' that you get from it. If your intention is to get the HashMap from the ArrayList, it would be:

```
map1 = Globals.mylist.get(i);
```

The second problem is:

```
Globals.mylist.remove(i);
```

You are removing the entry whilst also looping over the list it is in. When you do the remove, the ArrayList indexes change. Say you have 3 items:

- Index 0: Item 1
- Index 1: Item 2
- Index 2: Item 3

The first iteration of the loop has i = 0. When you remove index 0, the list becomes:

- Index 0: Item 2
- Index 1: Item 3

On the next iteration of the loop, i = 1. When you remove index 1, the list is then:

- Index 0: Item 2

At this point, the size of the list is 1. The loop then stops because 'i< Globals.mylist.size()' is no longer true. To avoid this problem, you should avoid removing from, or adding to, a collection whilst iterating over it. The solution here is to simply clear the collection after the loop has completed:

```
Globals.mylist.clear();
```